# Passing props to another component in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a component like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InputText extends Component  {
  render = () => {    
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.label}
        <input type="text" name={this.props.name} id={this.props.id} class={this.props.class} required={this.props.extraValue}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default InputText
```

I am using above component like below

```
<InputText name="paper" class="pen" id="mouse" extraValue="required"/>
```

I am getting output like below

```
<input type="text" name="paper" id="mouse" class="pen" required="">
```

Why the `extraValue` value is not working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`required` is a `Boolean`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). You should pass it like this

```
<InputText name="paper" class="pen" id="mouse" extraValue={true} />
```

Or

```
<InputText name="paper" class="pen" id="mouse" extraValue />
```

Comment: Thanks @Dupocas. I am still getting output like `<input type="text" name="paper" id="mouse" class="pen" required="">` using your solution. It should be `<input type="text" name="paper" id="mouse" class="pen" required="required">`.

Comment: @abuabu The value of the `required` attribute on the DOM element is not relevant. If it is present, it means that the input is required. So `required=""`, `required="required"` or `required="foo"` all make the input required. It would only not be required if the attribute is missing all together. React adds it with an empty string as the value because it doesn't really matter what the value is.